# Como escrever essa query utilizando o Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Preciso escrever uma SQL específica num projeto `Laravel` mas não consigo converter o `SQL` pra sintaxe do `Eloquent`, basicamente, preciso fazer esse `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM `movimentacoes` 
    WHERE nome LIKE '%pattern%' AND grupo_id = id AND (custo_id != 0 OR custo_id IS NULL);
```

Até a restrição do campo `grupo_id`, consigo escrever:

```
return $this->movimentacoes
               ->where('nome','LIKE','%'.$nome.'%')
               ->where('grupo_id', "=" ,$id)
               ->orderBy('nome', 'asc')
               ->paginate($this->PAGINATE);
```

Intuitivamente, para acrescentar a restrição do campo `custo_id`, eu deveria apenas adicionar:

```
    return $this->movimentacoes
                           ->where('nome','LIKE','%'.$id.'%')
                           ->where('grupo_id','=',$id)
/*ADD*/                    ->where('custo_id','=',$custo_id)->orWhereNull('custo_id')
                           ->orderBy('nome', 'asc')
                           ->paginate($this->PAGINATE);
```

mas ao invés do retorno ser o mesmo que a SQL que citei retornaria, o retorno é o mesmo que a seguinte SQL retornaria:

```
SELECT * FROM `movimentacoes` 
    WHERE nome LIKE '%pattern%' AND grupo_id = id AND (custo_id != 0) OR custo_id IS NULL;
```

Perceba que a diferença entre as duas SQL está na posição de um único parênteses, porém o resultado é totalmente diferente.

Preciso que a declaração de que o `custo_id` pode ser diferente de `0` ou `nulo`, pois apenas diferente de 0 não me retorna registros nulos.

Comment: Deu certo João ? algumas das resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Dessa `SQL`:

```
SELECT * FROM `movimentacoes` 
    WHERE nome LIKE '%pattern%' AND grupo_id = id AND (custo_id != 0 OR custo_id IS NULL);
```

Para `Eloquent Model`:

```
return $this->movimentacoes
            ->where('nome','LIKE','%'.$nome.'%')
            ->where('grupo_id', "=" ,$id)
            ->where(function($query) { // aqui a abordagem
                $query->where('id', '<>', 0)
                      ->orWhereNull('id');
            })
            ->orderBy('nome', 'asc')
            ->paginate($this->PAGINATE);
```

Esse tipo de abordagem no [Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries) é chamado de [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping).

Answer (score 0):

Para agrupar múltiplas condições você deve passar uma função anônima na chamada do `where`. Por exemplo:

```
$query->where(function ($condicao) {
    $condicao->where('custo_id','=',$custo_id)->orWhereNull('custo_id');
});
```

Dessa forma o SQL gerado vai incluir os parênteses no lugar correto.